# UML / Visual Paradigm: a C# (Win)Form in the code generation

Tags: c#, forms, uml, diagram, paradigms

I am creating a class diagram in Visual Paradigm and I am struggling with one thing. How do I specify that a class is in fact a form. So when I export the diagram to code, it wont become a normal class but instead it will become a form. A form which can hold buttons, ListBoxes, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: You can just derive from Form like so : class MyClass : Form

Comment: I've done this and it still exports it as a normal class.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Forms are "normal" classes.

Comment: Yeah, but when they are created, for example in Visual Studio, they differ from normal classes. They have a design view, normal code for events and another file.

Answer (score 0):

You intend to specify in your *Visual Paradigm* (VP) diagram a dependency on [*Form*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a class available in the *.NET framework*.

It seems there is no clear explanation how to do that specific operation in the VP documentation. However, there is an [article that covers the topic](http://knowhow.visual-paradigm.com/code-engineering/how-to-use-jdk-classes-in-diagrams/) with *Java SE* classes. This article uses the *Java* platform sources (available as a zip file in the *JDK* since *Java 6*) to extract the classes in a specific project. Then the reversed project is registered as a *referenced project* in your model project.

It seems this is possible to do a similar operation with *.NET* dlls instead of *Java* sources (have a look at the linked article - the screenshot for step 2). For that you have to identify the relevant dll(s) in your environment: I guess the *Microsoft .NET framework*, not *Mono*. According to [a Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ff462634%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the appropriate file would be something like *System.Windows.Forms.dll*. You should be able to find that file in your environment. On the identification of the relevant dll(s), I can't help you further (being myself a *Java* developer working on Linux).

Beware: your library project should be quite important as you will have all the dll classes represented. This is probably the reason why the documentation makes the reversal in a separated project and not in the real model project (another reason could be the possibility to use the classes in other projects).

Comment: This looks promising. I will take a look tomorrow and try to work something out. Thank you!